# Hard question on line integral? $\int_\gamma (\operatorname{Re}(z))\,dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Find the line integral
$$\int_\gamma (\operatorname{Re}(z))\,dz$$ where $\gamma$ is a line segment from 1 to $i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the definition of the line integral, i.e.

$$\int_\gamma f(z) dz = \int_a^b f(\gamma(x)) \cdot \gamma'(x) dx,$$

where $\gamma : [a,b] \rightarrow \Bbb{C}$.

In your case, you have $\gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow \Bbb{C}, t \mapsto (1-t) + t \cdot i$.

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer please?

Comment: You have $\gamma'(t) = i - 1$. Furthermore, $\Re(\gamma(t)) = 1-t$. Thus, your answer is $\int_\gamma f(z) dz = \int_0^1 (1-t) \cdot (i-1) dt = \frac{i-1}{2}$. You should have been able to do that yourself with the hint I gave you.

Answer (score 0):

The integral is $$I=\int_{0}^1 x dy=\int_{0}^1(1-y)dy=1/2$$ since the line segment $\gamma$ is $x+y=1$.